# Checkbox renders false but the data and DOM attribute is true

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a checkbox group component. Currently there is no native solution so I tried to create one on my own

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-checkbox
      v-for="(groupItem, index) in groupItems"
      :key="index"
      :label="groupItem.display"
      :value="groupItem.value"
      @change="onCheckboxUpdated(index)"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    groupItems: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCheckboxUpdated: function(index) {
      this.groupItems[index].value = !this.groupItems[index].value;
      this.$emit("checkboxGroupUpdated", this.groupItems);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This component should render a specific amount of checkboxes and fire an event with all the updated values.

When I pass in these values

```
    values: [
      {
        display: "Read permissions",
        value: true
      },
      {
        display: "Write permissions",
        value: false
      },
      {
        display: "Delete permissions",
        value: false
      }
    ]
```

the first generated checkbox renders a false state although the DOM element is set to true

[image]

When toggling the checkbox it will work fine the next time.

I created an example to reproduce the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxgroup-l8gcg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expand the `v-model` of a `v-checkbox` you'll need to use `input-value` as the prop rather than `value`.

```html
:input-value="groupItem.value"
```

See:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/27d5fdd32dc7c8a9af38f823d1574d92b211d405/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable.js#L14

That's a mixin that's included in `v-checkbox`.

While `input-value` is documented, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api, you do have to dig a bit to find it.

Unrelated to your problem, your current implementation of a checkbox group violates one-way data flow. You are mutating an object that has been passed via a prop.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

I'll leave it to you to decide whether you care.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Vue.js ignores the `value` of inputs.  You need to use `v-model` instead.

```
<v-checkbox
  v-for="(groupItem, index) in groupItems"
  :key="index"
  :label="groupItem.display"
  v-model="groupItem.value"
  @change="onCheckboxUpdated(index)"
></v-checkbox>
```

From the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.